guarantees, if any, on the conservation of value representation, under low-level creation/destruction of objects
They are regularly questions on SO about the validity of type-punning operations. For instance I contributed to a recent one: Is reinterpret_cast from char* to uint32_t* undefined behaviour in CPP?.
But I have a question that occurred to me when answering the above, that I can illustrate with this snippet:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

struct S {
    alignas(std::uint64_t) alignas(std::uint32_t)
        std::array<std::byte, sizeof(std::uint64_t)> storage = {some init values};
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    std::uint64_t* pi64 = std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t>(s.storage.data());
    // implicitely creating an uint32_t at the same location, ending lifetime of the uint64_t there
    std::uint32_t* pi32 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(s.storage.data()));
    // is there any guarantee that the value representation is unchanged?
    pi64 = std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t>(s.storage);
    // is s.storage guaranteed to be unchanged?
}

This is, so far, a theoretical code, as there is no compiler support I know of for std::start_lifetime_as. But I deem it useful to illustrate my understanding issue.
When defining pi64, I explicitly start a std::uint64_t object whose value representation is, on the byte level, the one I stored within the bytes array.
But then I'm implicitly creating an overlapping std::uint32_t which, AFAIU, ends the lifetime of the mentioned std::uint64_t object.
What happen to the underlying bytes? What are the standard rules (I know that unsigned char/std::byte arrays have special rules)?

I'm leaving the original question above but regarding https://stackoverflow.com/a/61442225/21691539, this snippet is meaningless as std::uint32_t* pi32 = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(s.storage.data())); is not, contrary to my claim above, a storage reuse.
The meaningful snippet would be:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

struct S {
    alignas(std::uint64_t) alignas(
        std::uint32_t) std::array<std::byte, sizeof(std::uint64_t)> storage = {
        some init values};
};

int main() {
    S s;
    // explicitly creating an uint64_t at the storage location
    std::uint64_t* pi64 =
        std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t>(s.storage.data());
    // explicitly reusing storage, thus ending the uint64_t lifetime
    new (storage.data()) std::byte[sizeof(std::uint64_t)];
    // implicitely creating an uint32_t at the same location, ending lifetime of
    // the uint64_t there
    std::uint32_t* pi32 =
        std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(s.storage.data()));
    // explicitly re-creating an uint64_t at the storage location
    // is it sufficient to end the uint32_t lifetime or do I need an explicit
    // storage reuse as above?
    pi64 = std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t>(s.storage);
    // is s.storage guaranteed to be unchanged?
}

So the question remains the same, saying it another way: is *pi64 guaranteed to be the same before and after the storage reuse?
NB this snippet may still be incorrect, see the comment before the second std::start_lifetime_as. One may tell me in comment if I need an extra line to end the std::uint32_t lifetime and I will fix the snippet accordingly.

Regarding the first snippet

But then I'm implicitly creating an overlapping std::uint32_t

No, you are not.
You wrote std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(s.storage.data())) which is undefined behavior if there isn't a std::uint32_t object at the pointer fed to std::launder (see Precondition for std::launder).
Neither reinterpret_cast nor std::launder implicitly create objects, so the only object within the storage is one of type std::uint64_t, making this undefined behavior.
Your example would make sense if you instead wrote
std::uint32_t* pi32 = std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint32_t>(s.storage.data()));


What happen to the underlying bytes?

They remain untouched. [obj.lifetime] p3 explains that for std::start_lifetime_as

The object representation of [the new object] is the contents of the storage prior to the call to start_lifetime_as. [...]  except that the storage is not accessed.

std::start_lifetime_as does not access any of the bytes belonging to the storage; it can be seen purely as an instruction to the compiler.
Therefore, you can chain together as many std::start_lifetime_as calls with the same storage together as you want, and you will always get the same value for the same type.
Regarding the second snippet
new wipes out the bytes, meaning that the value of the std::uint64_t is not preserved, and the subsequent call to std::start_lifetime_as is UB.
This happens because objects created by new have dynamic storage duration ([expr.new] p10), which means:

When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the bytes comprising the storage for the object have the following initial value:

If the object has dynamic storage duration, or [...], the bytes have indeterminate values; [...]


- [basic.indet] p1.1
In practice, it's not like the compiler will forcefully scramble the bytes somehow; it just means that the compiler from then on considers the bytes to be indeterminate, even if they had some value prior to the new expression and the memory was not overwritten.
The call to std::start_lifetime_as is UB because it determines the value of the result as if through std::bit_cast, ([obj.lifetime] p3) and std::bit_cast is UB when producing an indeterminate result ([bit.cast] p2).
Note: The call to std::start_lifetime_as being UB seems like an unintentional consequence of forwarding the semantics to std::bit_cast; I've reported this defect at LWG4168.
Regardless, the use of new within storage where a std::uint64_t lived would kill the std::uint64_t, and that's the core of this Q&A.

std::uint32_t is an implicit lifetime type. "Objects of implicit-lifetime types can also be implicitly created by, except during constant evaluation, operations that begin lifetime of an array of type unsigned char or std::byte(since C++17), in which case such objects are created in the array,". The only way I see it can work is, when I'm using the storage, as if it was one for an ILT, everything is "as if" the object was actually created at the time of storage creation. Yet it conflicts with the reuse of the storage for another object of different implicit lifetime type. Don't you think so?

std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t> makes it impossible that there would be a std::uint32_t object within that storage under any circumstances. The as-if rule doesn't really matter because the code has undefined behavior so the compiler can do anything it wants anyway. Implicitly creating a std::uint32_t there is just fine (if you do it properly) and does not prevent you from reusing the storage for std::uint64_t again later, but you do need to worry about endianness in that case.

thx, but how does std::start_lifetime_as can prevent that. AFAIU: "The lifetime of an object ends when:... the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within it". std::uint32_t being also ILT, I thought it will reuse the storage, effectively ending the std::uint64_t lifetime?

std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint32_t> begins the lifetime of a std::uint32_t object. Without it, there is no such object. The fact that it's ILT is irrelevant here, there still is none. But yeah, beginning its lifetime would end the lifetime of the std::uint64_t. On the last line, you std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t> again, so you end the lifetime of whatever was there before and now treat the storage as containing a std::uint64_t. As long as you keep using std::start_lifetime_as, all is okay.

Does it mean that I'm misinterpreting ILT creation (reference in first comment, how should it be understand?)?

The first quote isn't wrong, but the second you dump a std::uint64_t into the byte array, it's irrelevant what implicit-lifetime types have lived there. They're all dead. You seem to forget that std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t> also ends the lifetime of other objects in the storage.

I agree with you on that. My assumptions were: 1- pi64 definition: explicitly start lifetime of a std::uint64_t; 2- pi32definition implicitly start lifetime of a std::uint32_t and implictly ends the previous std::uint64_t;3- pi64assignment explicitly start a new std::uint64_t (which happen to have the same value representation as the first one), implicitly ending the std::uint32_t. You seem to say that 2 is wrong and I don't get why.

@Oersted because neither std::launder nor reinterpret_cast start the lifetime of anything, and because std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t> killed anything implicitly created before. Where do you think that std::uint32_t object is supposed to be coming from?

From implicit lifetime object creation. I confess that I nether understood how compiler were managing that. The answer that was given to me was, as soon as the storage exists,  and you're using it as an object of implicit lifetime type, the compiler assumes that the object was already there (but with a potentially uninitialized value). Which rises questions such as this one, which can get much worse in multithread context (or not, because it would be a plane race condition I think). TBC

I couldn't find clearer explanation. I'm stumbling only on ILT definition, the same as provided by  cppreference. AFAIU https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html is going my way (only the storage is explicitly created). The role of std::start_lifetime_as is only to preserve the underlying bytes and set the value representation from these. In my snippet, I would have expected pi32 to have an indeterminate representation whose evaluation would be UB. I would have to do something like *pi32=some value; for the object to be in a valid state.

sidenote, it seems that std::launder may be useless in the case of an implicit object creation, it may matter only for 'new-placed' objects. Yet I don't think it's an issue to use it "by default".

As I've said many times, the initial implicit object creation is irrelevant because any std::uint32_t that may have lived in the array is killed by std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint64_t>. std::launder is sometimes useful in the context if implicit object creation because its precondition coerces an implicit object of a certain type to exist. Because no std::uint32_t exists, std::launder is undefined behavior in your example.

"Because no std::uint32_t exists, std::launder is undefined behavior in your example." in the first snippet? Not in the second one, isn't it?

@Oersted oh, I haven't noticed that you've updated the question with another snippet. The new answer should cover everything.

It raises many other questions in my head but this one is answered. Thanks for the enlightening discussion.
